# Calculate Variance Manually in R

Tags: r, statistics

I need your help here. I need to calculate variance manually in R. I have achieved it with this codes, it is to not robust enough for missing values and non-numeric data types.

```
a= c(1,2,3,4,5)
k=mean(a,na.rm = T)
storage=a
for(i in 1:length(a)) {
  storage[i]= ((i-k)^2)
}
storage =sum((storage)/(length(a)-1))
storage
```

I run into trouble when I have  a= c(1,2,3,4,5,c,NA)
Please how would I edit the code?

Comment: first line of function: `a = na.omit(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a for loop but that is really unnecessary, you can make a function to vectorise it which removes the NAs from the data as the first step, via conversion to character then numeric vector types (because `c` is a function)...

```
# Create data
set.seed(1)
x1 <- sample(1:10, 5)
x2 <- c(x1, c, NA)

# Make the function
varFunc <- function(x){
 # Convert to character then numeric (non numeric become NA) then remove NAs
  x <- as.numeric(as.character(x))[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x)))]
  # Return Variance 
  sum((x-mean(x))^2) / (length(x)-1)
}

# Use the function 
varFunc(x1)
varFunc(x2)

# Sanity check
var(x1)
var(x2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, a few observations:

1. In R, you can do an operation on the whole vector. E.g. `(c(1, 2, 3))^2` yields `1 4 9`. There's no need to use a `for` loop.
2. `mean` isn't the only function that needs `na.rm = TRUE`; `sum` does too.
3. In R, atomic vectors (which are pretty much all vectors that aren't a list) can only have elements of one single data type. There are four primary types: logical, integer, double and character. If there's more than one type in the vector, all the elements are **coerced** to be the same, in the following order: character → double → integer → logical. For example, `c(1, 'c')` will return the **character vector** `"1", "c"`. That's why you were having trouble. (Note: If there's an `NA` in the vector, its type will be the same type of the vector.)

Unfortunately for that specific vector, `c(1,2,3,4,5,c,NA)`, I don't think there's a simple way to coerce it to an integer. That's because it's a list that has a function as an element: the function `c()`.

However, this function works whenever `x` is an atomic vector:

```
variance <- function(x){
  x = as.numeric(x)
  x = na.omit(x)
  m = mean(x)
  return(
    sum((x-m)^2, na.rm = TRUE)/(length(x) - 1)
  )
}
```

First we coerce the vector to numeric, so we can deal with a vector like `c(1, 2, 'a')`. Then we remove the `NA`'s, so we don't have to write `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean` and `sum`. Then we just write down the formula.

A minor inconvenience is that when converting a character vector to numeric, we get a warning saying that `NA`s were generated. This can be solved if we write `x = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))` instead.

If you want your function to be able to handle lists with functions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach: first, clean up `a`. If you start with something like `a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "c", NA)`, then `a` will not be stored as a numeric variable (because of the non-numeric entry). You might first coerce it to a numeric vector, which will give an extra `NA` entry:

```
a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "c", NA)
a <- as.numeric(a)

a

## 1  2  3  4  5 NA NA
```

Then, you could subset the original vector by retaining only the entries from this that *are* numeric (by using `!`):

```
a <- a[!is.na(as.numeric(a))]

a

## 1  2  3  4  5
```

You could do these right after your initial declaration of `a`, for instance. Gregor Thomas also suggested `na.omit()`, which could work if combined properly with `as.numeric()`.

I notice that you computed the mean by using the built-in `mean()` function and using `na.rm = T`... if you're able to use that same approach here, note that `var()` also has an optional `na.rm = T` parameter. I suspect you're not allowed to use it since you were instructed to compute the variance by hand, but perhaps you could use this to *check* your answers.