# Difference in Variance computation

Tags: r, statistics

I have Manually computed the variance of two data sets using definitional, computational and normal R expressions.

```
 set.seed(12345)                        
 n <- 1e7                             
 df <- tibble(
   small = rnorm(n, mean=100, sd=1),
   large = rnorm(n, mean=1e8, sd=1)
 )

#Definitional
varFuncd <- function(x) {
  x <- as.numeric(as.character(x))[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x)))] 
  sum((x-mean(x))^2) / (length(x)-1)
}

#Computational 
varFuncc <- function(x){
  x <- as.numeric(as.character(x))[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x)))]
  (sum(x^2) - (sum(x)^2)/length(x))/(length(x)-1)
}
```

but the variance of the Large column produces an expected large result (1.6). Please what might be the reason?

My response is:

All the definitional expressions produced an expected variance of 1. However, the computation expression for "Large" produced a higher variance. Definitional expression produces a square of the difference - which translates to squaring relatively small values and produce more efficient results. While Computational uses difference of squares, when the underlying values are large, the difference of squares produces a less efficient result, because squaring large numbers produces super large figure s that become inefficient when divided by n-1.

Comment: Why do you convert to character and back again in the first line of each function?

Comment: This is why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132506/calculate-variance-manually-in-r/61133230#61133230

Answer (score 1):

I agree you're running into numerical stability problems as R uses double floating-point numbers for `numeric`. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) when discussing the specific representation for variance that you are using for `varFuncc`:

> *This equation should not be used for computations using floating point arithmetic 
>   because it suffers from [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) if the two components of the equation are similar in magnitude. There exist numerically stable alternatives.*